# divide the width of the screen between elements in relative layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

Let's say I have a button and an EditText, aligned at the same height(the bottom of the screen) and sharing the width of the screen. I want the button to take just the space it needs, and the editText to cover the rest of the width.

Up until now I've been using a linearLayout, where in this case I could put those two elements inside an horizontal linear layout, set the weight of the editText to 1 and the with of the button to wrap_content, and it would work.

However, I am not able to replicate this behaviour using a relative layout. I can put the editText at the bottom of the parent, and then set the button to its right, but I don't know how to make the editText fill the rest of the width respecting the button's space.

What's the correct way to do it?

Edit: this is what I have so far:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">



    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:hint="@string/editText_Hint"
        android:inputType="number" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/edittext"
        android:onClick="sendAnswer"
        android:text="@string/button_text" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And I want to replicate the behaviour of this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

   /*other stuff here*/

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edittext"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/editText_Hint"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:layout_weight="1"
           />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button_text"
            android:onClick="sendAnswer"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: please put Your xml code

Comment: @Dilavar Edited, the code is included now.

Comment: Button first(in XML)width wrap content, bottom and right of parent(align). Next edit bottom left parent(align) and to the right of button width 0dp

Comment: @kace91 could you put image of what you required?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, aligning the button right of the button and setting the `width` of the `edittext` to `match_parent` works fine for me.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Doing so the `edittext` looks as if goes till the border. To have better look add some margin to the right of the `edittext` using the attribute `android:layout_marginRight="5dp"`

**UPDATE**

If your requirement is to use the parent layout to be `Relative Layout`, the best solution for you to use a nested layout.

Use a `LinearLayout` nested within the Relative layout with its alignment `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` to the LinearLayout.

Sample given below,

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This is the best solution I've got so far, but I still don't like that, as you say, the editText seems to be filling the width overlapping with the button. I can change the layout:margin right manually by trial and error until it matches the width of the button, but there has to be a better way (plus that hardcoded number will probably not work when the width of the button changes on different languages)

Comment: @kace91 have a look at my update. It will be helpful if you are OK in using a Linear layout nested within your Relative layout. This implementation doesn't use hard coded values

Comment: Yeah I know that works, but I was trying to avoid nesting layouts as I read that it implies taking a hit in performance. Anyway, I found a solution that works without nesting, I posted it as a separate answer in case you want to check it. Thanks for the help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution myself. The trick was to set both elements at the bottom, then the edit text to width:0dp, alignParentLeft and toLeftOF the button (NOT alignLeft of the button, but toLeftOF the button). The button should be alignedto parent right and parent bottom.

The final code looks like this:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:hint="@string/editText_Hint"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
       >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:onClick="sendAnswer"
        android:text="@string/button_text" />
```